Relationship of flutter sdk to gradle version and jdk version
In which file  can view the gradle and jdk version recommended by the sdk.
When I upgrade gradle version, run project will report some issues.
Example: flutter-sdk version is flutter_3.22.2 and gradle version is gradle_8.0_bin

I hope can clearly see the relationship between them in flutter's sdk file.

Yes , There is relationship between gradle version and Flutter sdk version.
For gradle you can check android>gradle>wrapper>gralde-wrapper-properties for gradle versions .
follow this link to reslove the issues .
